# Issue in loading the .obj using three.js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, object, three.js

I am trying to load .obj file using three.js,
but unfortunately it's say the error that "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Below is the example link I am using

view-source:http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

CODE is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="info">
    <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
    </div>

    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 100;

            // scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
            scene.add( ambient );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
            directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
            scene.add( directionalLight );

            // texture

            var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                console.log( item, loaded, total );

            };

            var texture = new THREE.Texture();

            var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg', function ( image ) {

                texture.image = image;
                texture.needsUpdate = true;

            } );

            // model

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                        child.material.map = texture;

                    }

                } );

                object.position.y = - 80;
                scene.add( object );

            } );

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

If anybody has these above example working then please let me know how do you do?

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: You say you are trying to load a .obj file.... then why link to the threejs example? Is the example not loading for you? It loads ok for me. The 404 error simply means that the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: yes example is not loading object for me....could you please send me the working copy of example.

Comment: Are you trying to run it on your local machine?

Comment: yes i m running in my local machine...

Comment: Well, it is quite simple. The error is because the files are not bring found on your local machine. The paths should start with 'mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/' eg 'mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/obj/male02/male02.obj'

Comment: You might be better just downloading the whole three.js package as it contains all the examples and associated files.

Comment: i am put same path as in the example like 'obj/male02/male02.obj'......but its not working with me.....I am try in c# asp.net.....on which platform this example is working with you?

Comment: 'obj/male02/male02.obj' is a relative path from the html document. Since the html document is now on your local machine, it is looking for the .obj file relative to your local copy of the html. Let me give you an example. If you local copy is in a folder on your machine c://threejs/webgl_loader_obj.html. Then it is looking for the .obj file in c://threejs/obj/male02/male02.obj. I am unsure how I can explain this any clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much it try that....but its give me the error like "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Khant/Documents/visual%20studio%202013/Projects/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/obj/male02/male02.obj. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."......I think this error is in OBJLoader file

Comment: That is not an error with the OBJLoader. Change the path to the online file like I said in my second comment and this should not happen. I have spent enough time on this very trivial question.

Comment: not working still.....can you send me the code file of your so i can try same thing....thanks

Answer (score 8):

My issue in this case was allowing Mime Type on Windows Server.

You can either do it manually or in code:

Manual way:

1. Go to IIS settings
2. Open Mime Type settings
3. Click Add
4. Mime type extinsion: .obj
5. Mime type: application/octet-stream
6. Click Add
7. Restart your Site or application Pool

Code - put following into Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="application/octet-stream" /> 
    </staticContent>    
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm working on Asp.Net and Three.js. I tried this solution, It works fine

Answer (score 1):

A 404 error means the file cannot be found in the location you've defined it. If you're running in localhost, then in the same folder as your demo.html file, you should have:

- A directory called obj containing a directory called male02 containing a file called male02.obj
- A directory called textures containing a file called UV_Grid_Sm.jpg

The error means that you currently do not.

If you're an experienced developer, I guess you will be able to fix this now. If you're new to development and struggling to understand where your current links are pointing, perhaps spend a bit of time refreshing your understanding of absolute and relative links: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: HOw to give the physical path in loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object )?

Comment: i try to put on obj/male02/male02.obj but still same error of path

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and changed the Mime settings with no success. What seemed to resolve the issue was re-creating a new file directly from my web host panel and copying the .obj and .mtl code into it and re-naming it with the appropriate suffix.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You are unable to load .OBJ files using Three.js built in Methods.

this link -> https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader

### Solution

You **CANNOT** use `new THREE.OBJLoader();` you need to call it as `new OBJLoader();`

I have found the answer after reading & understanding the Three.js Site.

The method you are thinking unconsciously is called `ObjectLoader();` though it does not mean it is made to load .obj file type. Their working is different.

`ObjectLoader();` is made to load .JSON file type.

**What you need is a Three.js Addon called --->** `OBJLoader();`

#### how to get OBJLoader();

```
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
```

after importing the addon

```
const objLoader = new OBJLoader();

objLoader.load('./my-obj-folder/my-obj-file.obj',(PassingOBJ) => {
  scene.add(PassingOBJ);
  Generic Function();
});
```