# Three.js OBL Loader

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-modelling

I am having trouble viewing the models in this file. I found this example of three.js which simple loads an obj file. I am using visual studios. The code of the loader goes as followed.

The problems is that I am using visual studios to build and fun the project but when i run the project through visual studios, nothing shows. The screen is black, but if i actually go the location of the file and load the file in Firefox then the model loads. Also if i do the same thing but load the file through Google Chrome, nothing shows, its just a black screen. What could be the issue. ( I have webGl enabled in both browsers).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    body {
            font-family: Monospace;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #info {
            color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 100;
            display: block;
        }

            #info a, .button {
                color: #f00;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: underline;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <script>

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 100;

                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                // texture

                var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
                manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                    console.log( item, loaded, total );

                };

                var texture = new THREE.Texture();

                var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                    }
                };

                var onError = function ( xhr ) {
                };


                var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
                loader.load( 'textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg', function ( image ) {

                    texture.image = image;
                    texture.needsUpdate = true;

                } );

                // model

                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
                loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                            child.material.map = texture;

                        }

                    } );

                    object.position.y = - 80;
                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue in loading the .obj using three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809055/issue-in-loading-the-obj-using-three-js)